# How do I make a table view cell work as a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to make an app that the user will press a cell and the cell will function as a button, now how do I make the cell function as a button and do an action or how do I know which cell is being pressed?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Please read the document but basically when you set the delegate of the tableviewcontroller it calls this method when clicked:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

The indexpath holds the section and the row. If you are using only one section then `indexPath.row` will return the index of the cell that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You implement the [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a).

That method will be called whenever the user taps any of the cells. If the passed `indexPath` is the index path of your button cell, then you do whatever should happen.

Answer (score 0):

Read Apple's documentation on [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
And you will find `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this method gets called when the user taps a cell. `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` are your cell section and row indexs. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you simply want to run some code when a user touches a cell.

The UITableViewDelegate has a method called `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ([`UITableViewDelegate tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate))

Just implement that and you can do what you want in there.